# How to copy files in a directory that are not listed in a text file

Tags: bash

I have files in a directory, with a pattern in the filename ("IMP-"). I need to copy the files from the directory A to the directory B. But I also keep the files in the directory A. So in order to copy only the new files in directory B, I need, first to list each time I do a copy, the filenames in a text file (list.txt), and then to copy only the files that aren't listed in the text file.

exemple

Directory A (/home/ftp/recep/)
files, for example can be :

```
/home/recep/IMP-avis2018.txt
/home/recep/IMP-avis2018.pdf
/home/recep/IMP-avis2017.jpg
/home/recep/IMP-avis2017.pdf
```

Directory B (/home/ftp/transfert/)

In need to copy all files with IMP* to directory B (/home/ftp/transfert/). 
And when a new file is receive in drectory A, I need this file, and only this file, to be copied in directory B (where files only stay 2 hours max)

I tought maybe I could do something with rsync, but I could'n find an adequate option.
So maybe it could be a bash script.
Actions would be :

1. have a simple basic text file containing already proceed files (for example liste.txt)
2. find files in directory A containing pattern IMP
3. for each of these files, read the liste.txt file and if the file is not listed in liste.txt, copy it to the directory B

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? You can go with `find` to get all the files then do `comm -13` on sorted result of find and the file to get only files that are not listed in the text file, then pass it to `xargs cp` to copy them,.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my question was really incomplete.

I need to log every file I move from repository A to repository B because I only keep the file in the directory A. The directory B is a transit folder, the files will be then send to another server.

So I thought I could do it by using a loop, but I'm really a newb regarding bash.

for f in /home/recep/ ; do
if $f ==> I don't know whate code I could use, but the idea is : "if file is listed in list.txt do nothing" else copy the file in the directory B"

Sorry if I wasted you time

Comment: `I have files in a directory` - can you post an example number (like 10)  of filenames you have in your directory with the pattern? `I also keep the files in the directory A` - can you post example filenames in directory A? `the filenames in a text file (list.txt)` - can you post an example of the text file? And finally - for the examples you provide, can you post example action (which file should be copied where and why), the expected output? Only _after_ you specify requirements, you can start coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the option `-n`. The man page says:

> -n, --no-clobber
>       do not overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)

So

```
cp -n A/* B/
```

should copy all files from A to B, except those that are already in B.

Another way would be rsync:

```
rsync -vu A/* B/
```

This syncs the files from A to B and prints the file that were actually copied.